# import menu to browser window by "require" function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, commonjs

I am working on a electron demo by following [this tutorial](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-menu/).

just wondering what happened in the require line of code.

**./menu/mainmenu.js** defines the menu items.

```
const {Menu} = require('electron')
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app

const template = [
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      {
        role: 'undo'
      },
      {
        role: 'redo'
      },
      {
        type: 'separator'
      },
      {
        role: 'cut'
      },
      {
        role: 'copy'
      },
      {
        role: 'paste'
      },
      {
        role: 'pasteandmatchstyle'
      },
      {
        role: 'delete'
      },
      {
        role: 'selectall'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
let win;

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 880,
    height: 660,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  require('./menu/mainmenu') //does this line copied the whole mainmenu.js file?
}
```

does the `require('./menu/mainmenu')`  copy whole file into `main.js`?

Or imported some modules? In the mainmenu.js file There is no `export` keyword.

according to the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/),

*"The basic functionality of require is that it reads a JavaScript file, executes the file, and then proceeds to return the exports object."*

Comment: require here doesn't copy file around (unlike `c++` #include)

Comment: to explain, that require *is supposed to* execute that file (which imho should never be rely on)

Comment: @appleapple any suggestions why should never rely on the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` here doesn't copy file around (unlike `c++` #include)

Instead it execute the file and return the exported items (if any)

---

Since there is no `export` in `'./menu/mainmenu'` when you call `require`, it simply executed that file.

The problem with this approach is `require` would only process that file ***once****, the proper way is actually export something which can be used multiple times.

---

example:

`./menu/mainmenu.js`

```
//...
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
export default ()=>Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

`main.js`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

let win;

function createWindow () {
  //...

  const setmenu = require('./menu/mainmenu') // you can put this at top, too
  setmenu();

  // or you can execute it inline
  // require('./menu/mainmenu')()
}
```

note: you may need https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports or some workaround to make `require` and `default export` works together.

---

*the problem with this is you cannot really rely on it to work everytime, e.g. change menu from A -> B -> A  , the second `require('A')` would *silently* do nothing.